# How to get ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Facebook, Twitter, etc. sign-on working with SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working through this tutorial to get the OAuth stuff working:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

I've only just gotten as far as turning on SSL and when I press F5 to start the app and, the start page doesn't load.

I've not gotten as far as actually turning on any of the OAuth providers or anything, it simply won't work with SSL.

I know this isn't a ton to go on but perhaps someone has seen this before and solved it?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Does it work without SSL enabled?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I select my web application project in the solution explorer and press F4 to view properties. Then I set `SSL Enabled` to `True`. In this case it is also important that Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

[image: Project Development Server properties]

Next I edit the project's Web settings and change the Project URL to the SSL URL from the first properties panel, by selecting the web application project in solution explorer and pressing Alt+Enter and then clicking Web on the left side. In these screenshots you can see that my SSL URL has the port 44301.

[image: Project web settings]

Comment: I was hoping someone wouldn't post this! :)  Kidding...mine looks exactly like this. Also, I had a few minutes on my work machine and got this working out of the box. My problems are on my home machine (same OS version, same VS version, etc.) but it won't work at home.

Comment: Perhaps you have some interesting firewall rules or end point protection.